# How to connect to a site's endpoints with wcf client

Tags: web-services, wcf, endpoint, wcf-client

I need to connect to a site's endpoints and call it's methods.
Is it possible to do this creating a WCF Client?
I don't know which technology is used by the site for it's
web services. I have only been given the endpoints to communicate.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the local address and port as well as the name of the service, the procedure is the same as the WCF Web service.